# Reactjs, import files error. Run in chrome, not working in firefox?

Tags: reactjs

I have imported file (commonFunction). Although code runs just fine on Chrome, it gets "ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 7 failed." in firefox.

[image]

[image]

File import: `import {
  getListMerchantStatus,
} from '../../../utils/commonFunction';`

Comment: To me it looks as if that js file is just missing. Double check the generated production build and what's on your server.

Comment: Could you please add your code as text instead of as image.
Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them